# PHP autoload class not found

Tags: php, spl, spl-autoload-register

I'm having a problem with PHP autoload with a specific class, where it keeps saying it's not found.

Error:

```
Warning: require_once(Models/BaseModel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/icompare/init.php on line 29

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Models/BaseModel.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/icompare/lib') in /var/www/html/icompare/init.php on line 29
```

How my autoload is started in `init.php`:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.APP_ROOT_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'lib');
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register(function($className){
  $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
  $file = $className.".php";
  // echo 'Loading file: '.$file.PHP_EOL;
  require_once $file;
});
```

My folder structure:

[image]

`BaseModel` class (it's not the full file):

```
<?php
/**
 * Model Base CRUD Banco de Dados
 */
namespace Models;

class BaseModel {
  protected $tableName = null;

  public function find($value, $field = 'id', $fieldType = \PDO::PARAM_STR){
    if(!isset($this->tableName) || empty($this->tableName)){
      return null;
    }

    $DB = new \DB;
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = :value", $this->tableName, $field);
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, $fieldType);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Somehow PHP is looking for a "Models/" capitalized folder? 
Have you guys ever experienced that before?

Comment: correct the file path in `require_once`

Comment: You're generating the filename from the classname by doing a string replace of backslash to slash, and the classname it's looking for is `\Models\BaseModel`, so the filename it generates is `.../Models/BaseModel.php` but your directory is named `models`. If you follow PSR-4 (which you should) then your namespaces should match your directories and your files should match your classes.

Comment: put `__dir__` in your autoloader, when it fails your see the complete path

Comment: @AlexHowansky that makes sense, but in that case, which is the best option to use? Capitalize my dir names or lowercase my namespaces to match everything? (My files all match with my classes name)

Comment: See [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for best practices. Generally, uppercase.

Comment: @AlexHowansky could you please answer it so I can accept it as the best answer? That's the first time I try to implement myself an autoload, didn't know these rules to follow, great (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're generating the filename from the classname by doing a string replace of backslash to slash:

```
  $className = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
```

Since the classname you're trying to load is `\Models\BaseModel`, the filename that gets generated is `.../Models/BaseModel.php`. However, your file's actual name is `.../models/BaseModel.php`, so the `require` fails because unixy operating systems have case sensitive filenames. If you follow [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) (which you should) then your namespaces should match your directories and your files should match your classes. Thus, the class `\Models\BaseModel` should be defined in a file named `.../Models/BaseModel.php`.